# Casing of wieners

Tags: sausages

I bought wieners today at a local store and they come with a casing that has writing and a drawing of a chicken. I've never bought wieners like these before and I would like to know if I should remove said casing before cooking

Comment: Could we get a picture? (Ok, mostly because we are curious, printing sounds suspiciously non-edible...)

Comment: There are certainly edible dyes... but we can't really know whether it's an edible or inedible casing without at least seeing it... have you inspected the packaging to see if there is a warning to remove the casing?

Comment: I'm a student in Georgia (next to russia) and I can't read or write yet (first year), that's basically the reason I'm asking since usually I bought the packaged wieners which were similar to the ones I used to cook before moving to Georgia. 

Here is a picture:
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/116964493447135234/323868437388591107/20170612_205641.jpg

Comment: Assuming that you have had both nylon packed and gut packed wieners before, it will be easy to notice the difference - or are you only familiar with one type of the two?

Comment: only fimiliar with one type

Comment: Cant read it myself, you may need to find a local, but just going by looks with the color and bold printing it does not strike me as edible and definitely looks like man-made casing.  Some of those are still edible, but the looks would say to me no.  Possibly intended to cook in and then remove, but has a very plastic like appearance.  Pending finding a local who can tell you I personally would assume not intended to be eaten.

Answer (score 3):

My colleague reads Georgian and lived in Georgia for many years. He advises that the casing reads "Chicken little sausages" and "should definitely not be eaten." He's familiar with the type of product, though not the specific brand, and indicates they're to be opened/unwrapped and the wrapping discarded.